# Why is the move constructor not called?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

As per my understanding, the move constructor will be called when there is a temporary object created. Here the `getA()` function is returning a temporary object but my program is not printing the message from the move constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
        cout<<"Hi from default\n";
    }

    A(A && obj)
    {
        cout<<"Hi from move\n";
    } 
};

A getA()
{
    A obj;
    cout<<"from getA\n";
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    A b(getA());

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was searching with move constructor and google is not leading me to that page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to optimise out the instance `obj` and send the object directly back to the caller without a conceptual value copy being taken.

This is called **named** return value optimisation (NRVO). It's a more aggressive optimisation than classical *return value optimisation* (RVO) that a compiler can invoke to obviate the value copy of an anonymous temporary.

For the avoidance of doubt the compiler can do this **even if** there is a side-effect in doing so (in your case the lack of console output).

Comment: What was wrong with the dupe target?

Comment: It was more to do with RVO not (the more recent) NRVO. IMHO a duplicate is only a good one if it's pretty exact.

Comment: Half of the answers talked about and example NRVO.